# keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException; androidlampung.jks

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukjE9.png)why is this when I want to create a keytool there is a problem like

[image: this]

[image]

[image]

Comment: pls help me....

Comment: Error is obvious from the looks of it the filepath .jks does not exist. can you confirm if there is actually a file at this path. also please share the minimal reproduction steps so we can understand better.

Comment: Or more likely `C:\Users\PC_03\` folder doesn't exist.

Comment: I've sent some photos to clarify my problem

Comment: please remove underscore ( _ ) in PC 03 inside you'r path

Answer (score 0):

There is no _ in PC 03 in the folder path that you have added. Please remove the _ from the path specified

Comment: sir see my latest photo

Comment: Your latest photo also shows no _

Comment: Please remove space from the folder name and try again